# translate SQL join to JPQL

Tags: jpa, pagination, jpql, toplink

Currently, **all** articles in the join for the `JPQL` query are returned in the `getRangeOfArticles` method, whereas only a **range** of articles should get returned.

The MySQL console output I'm after, but would like to implement in JPQL:

```
mysql> 
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles LEFT OUTER JOIN newsgroups ON articles.NEWSGROUP_ID=newsgroups.ID  WHERE newsgroups.NEWSGROUP = "gwene.com.economist" AND articles.ID BETWEEN 450 AND 453;
+-----+---------------+--------------+------+---------------------+
| ID  | MESSAGENUMBER | NEWSGROUP_ID | ID   | NEWSGROUP           |
+-----+---------------+--------------+------+---------------------+
| 450 |           554 |            5 |    5 | gwene.com.economist |
| 451 |           555 |            5 |    5 | gwene.com.economist |
| 452 |           556 |            5 |    5 | gwene.com.economist |
| 453 |           557 |            5 |    5 | gwene.com.economist |
+-----+---------------+--------------+------+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> show tables;
+------------------+
| Tables_in_usenet |
+------------------+
| articles         |
| newsgroups       |
+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> describe articles;
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID            | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| MESSAGENUMBER | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| NEWSGROUP_ID  | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe newsgroups;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID        | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| NEWSGROUP | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I'm trying to replicate that SQL query in JPQL in the `getRangeOfArticles` method:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.persistence.*;
import net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Article;
import net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Newsgroup;

class DatabaseUtils {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(DatabaseUtils.class.getName());
    private EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("USENETPU");
    private EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    //SELECT MAX(MESSAGENUMBER) FROM articles LEFT OUTER JOIN newsgroups ON articles.NEWSGROUP_ID=newsgroups.ID  WHERE newsgroups.NEWSGROUP = "gwene.com.economist";
    public int getMaxMessageNumber(Folder folder) {
        int maxMessageNumber = 0;
        String newsgroup = folder.getFullName();
        String queryString = "select max(article.messageNumber) from Article article left join article.newsgroup newsgroup where newsgroup.newsgroup = '" + newsgroup + "'";
        try {
            maxMessageNumber = (Integer) em.createQuery(queryString).getSingleResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.severe("setting max to zero for " + newsgroup);
        }
        LOG.fine(folder.getFullName() + "\t" + maxMessageNumber);
        return maxMessageNumber;
    }

    //SELECT * FROM articles LEFT OUTER JOIN newsgroups ON articles.NEWSGROUP_ID=newsgroups.ID  WHERE newsgroups.NEWSGROUP = "gwene.com.economist" AND articles.ID BETWEEN 450 AND 500;   
    public List<Article> getRangeOfArticles(Page page) {
        String fullNewsgroupName = page.getFolder().getFullName();
        int minRange = page.getMin();
        int maxRange = page.getMax();
        String queryString = "select article from Article article left join article.newsgroup newsgroup where newsgroup.newsgroup = :newsGroupParam";
        TypedQuery<Article> query = em.createQuery(queryString, Article.class);
        query.setParameter("newsGroupParam", fullNewsgroupName);
        List<Article> results = query.getResultList();
        LOG.info(results.toString());
        return results;
    }

    public void persistArticle(Message message, Folder folder) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        String fullNewsgroupName = folder.getFullName();
        Newsgroup newsgroup = null;
        TypedQuery<Newsgroup> query = em.createQuery("SELECT n FROM Newsgroup n WHERE n.newsgroup = :newsGroupParam", Newsgroup.class);
        query.setParameter("newsGroupParam", fullNewsgroupName);
        try {
            newsgroup = query.getSingleResult();
            LOG.fine("found " + query.getSingleResult());
        } catch (javax.persistence.NoResultException e) {
            LOG.fine(e + "\ncould not find " + fullNewsgroupName);
            newsgroup = new Newsgroup(folder);
            em.persist(newsgroup);
        } catch (NonUniqueResultException e) {
            LOG.warning("\nshould never happen\t" + fullNewsgroupName);
        } /*
         * finally { if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
         * em.getTransaction().rollback(); }
         */
        Article article = new Article(message, newsgroup);
        em.persist(article);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public void close() {
        em.close();
        emf.close();//necessary?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query a collection of `Article`s by their `Newsgroup`'s name you can do something like this:

```
String queryString = "select a from Article a where a.newsgroup.newsgroup = :newsGroupParam";
TypedQuery<Article> query = em.createQuery(queryString, Article.class);
query.setParameter("newsGroupParam", fullNewsgroupName);
List<Article> results = query.getResultList();
```

Don't write joins in JPQL, let JPA do the work for you.

As an extra tip, you should always write your queries like this to prevent SQL injection.

```
public int getMaxMessageNumber(Folder folder) {
    int maxMessageNumber = 0;
    String queryString = "select max(a.messageNumber) from Article a where a.newsgroup.newsgroup = :newsgroup";
    Query q = em.createQuery(queryString);
    q.setParameter("newsgroup", folder.getFullName());
    try {
        maxMessageNumber = (Integer) q.getSingleResult();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.severe("setting max to zero for " + newsgroup);
    }
    LOG.fine(folder.getFullName() + "\t" + maxMessageNumber);
    return maxMessageNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in terms of the query, I believe it's `String queryString = "select article from Article article left join article.newsgroup newsgroup where newsgroup.newsgroup = :newsGroupParam and article.messageNumber between 100 and 500";` although I need to add some parameters in there for ranges.  See `getRangeOfArticles` below:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.persistence.*;
import net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Article;
import net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Newsgroup;
import net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Usenet;

class DatabaseUtils {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(DatabaseUtils.class.getName());
    private EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("USENETPU");
    private EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    //SELECT MAX(MESSAGENUMBER) FROM articles LEFT OUTER JOIN newsgroups ON articles.NEWSGROUP_ID=newsgroups.ID  WHERE newsgroups.NEWSGROUP = "gwene.com.economist";
    public int getMaxMessageNumber(Folder folder) {
        int maxMessageNumber = 0;
        String newsgroup = folder.getFullName();
        String queryString = "select max(article.messageNumber) from Article article left join article.newsgroup newsgroup where newsgroup.newsgroup = '" + newsgroup + "'";
        try {
            maxMessageNumber = (Integer) em.createQuery(queryString).getSingleResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.severe("setting max to zero for " + newsgroup);
        }
        LOG.fine(folder.getFullName() + "\t" + maxMessageNumber);
        return maxMessageNumber;
    }

    //SELECT * FROM articles LEFT OUTER JOIN newsgroups ON articles.NEWSGROUP_ID=newsgroups.ID  WHERE newsgroups.NEWSGROUP = "gwene.com.economist" AND articles.ID BETWEEN 450 AND 500;   
    public List<Article> getRangeOfArticles(Page page) {
        String fullNewsgroupName = page.getFolder().getFullName();
        int minRange = page.getMin();
        int maxRange = page.getMax();
        String queryString = "select article from Article article left join article.newsgroup newsgroup where newsgroup.newsgroup = :newsGroupParam and article.messageNumber between 100 and 500";
        TypedQuery<Article> query = em.createQuery(queryString, Article.class);
        query.setParameter("newsGroupParam", fullNewsgroupName);
        List<Article> articles = query.getResultList();
        Usenet usenet = Usenet.INSTANCE;
        for (Article article : articles) {
            List<String> string = new ArrayList<>();
            string.add(article.getId().toString());
            string.add(Long.toString(article.getMessageNumber()));
            Message message = usenet.getMessage(page.getFolder(), article.getMessageNumber());
            try {
                string.add(message.getSubject());
            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DatabaseUtils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            Newsgroup n = article.getNewsgroup();
            string.add(n.getNewsgroup());
            LOG.info(string.toString());
        }
        return articles;
    }

    public void persistArticle(Message message, Folder folder) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        String fullNewsgroupName = folder.getFullName();
        Newsgroup newsgroup = null;
        TypedQuery<Newsgroup> query = em.createQuery("SELECT n FROM Newsgroup n WHERE n.newsgroup = :newsGroupParam", Newsgroup.class);
        query.setParameter("newsGroupParam", fullNewsgroupName);
        try {
            newsgroup = query.getSingleResult();
            LOG.fine("found " + query.getSingleResult());
        } catch (javax.persistence.NoResultException e) {
            LOG.fine(e + "\ncould not find " + fullNewsgroupName);
            newsgroup = new Newsgroup(folder);
            em.persist(newsgroup);
        } catch (NonUniqueResultException e) {
            LOG.warning("\nshould never happen\t" + fullNewsgroupName);
        } /*
         * finally { if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
         * em.getTransaction().rollback(); }
         */
        Article article = new Article(message, newsgroup);
        em.persist(article);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public void close() {
        em.close();
        emf.close();//necessary?
    }
}
```

However, I seem to get some errors:

```
Aug 06, 2012 12:00:02 AM net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Usenet getMessage
SEVERE: null
javax.mail.MessageRemovedException: No such article: 273
```

so perhaps there's an error with the query syntax or meaning, or I have a logical error.